# Is there any diagram for unit-tests?

Tags: unit-testing, diagrams

I'm writing a software library for some numerical computations. I'd like to use Boost Unit Test framework to write a hierarchical unit-test covering not only basic input/output behavior of functions but also the higher functionality, e.g. correct results to some test problems etc.

However, I'm afraid, that I'll get lost in a complexity of tests. Is there any standard way to list them? Like some unit-test diagram?

Comment: "I'm afraid, that I'll get lost in a complexity of tests" - is this based on facts because you have already written several hundred tests and loosing control, or is this just something you assume which could happen, though you did not write many tests so far?

Comment: @DocBrown I assume it will happen - I have several tens of tests and I see, that there will be needed much larger number.

Comment: Unit tests are for humans. Write them to be readable. Code review them just like normal code. If anyone is getting lost in them then write clearer tests.

Comment: @candied_orange I'm not having problems with unit-test code readability. I'm trying to describe a structure of a large number of unit-tests.

Comment: Describe the structure how? Say I'm a new coder looking at all these tests. Why do I care about their structure? What do I need to be able to do that understanding this structure will help me do?

Comment: @candied_orange Then you'll be able to see, if there is a majority of use-cases covered by tests or if you need to write some more of them. Also, it could help you to plan new unit-test before implementing a new modules to your project.

Comment: So you are trying to help people map unit tests to use-cases with this "diagram". The number one way I do that is with good names, sensible ordering, and grouping. I've sometimes created multiple test classes for one class just because I wanted to clearly show the humans one group of tests was distinct from another.

Comment: @candied_orange Yes, that's what I want to. And your proposed structure seems like the reasonable way.

Comment: If you have lots of inputs and outputs to test the same bits of logic, then [Data-Driven Testing](https://smartbear.com/learn/automated-testing/introduction-to-data-driven-testing/) might be the answer.

Comment: So, is your question about "how to document the structure of unit tests" or "how do I organize my test cases when only inputs or outputs vary?"

Comment: @GregBurghardt My question is the first one - how to document the structure of unit tests?

Comment: **Arrange, Act, Assert.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a "standard diagram", but there are naming conventions for unit tests around, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155436/unit-test-naming-best-practices) or [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/7-popular-unit-test-naming).

I would recommend first and foremost to have a good structure and documentation for the library. Then, one should establish a rigid naming convention for the tests so it stays easy to see which test belongs to which part of the library. In general, the structure of unit tests should follow the structure of the subject under test. For example, for every class or module `Foo`, the related tests could be in a class `TestFoo` or `FooTest`. For a more sophisticated convention, follow the links above.

If you go that route, the structure of your lib imposes enough structure on your tests that you do not need some extra "list" or "diagram".

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to reduce the complexity of tests. For instance, with *property-based* testing (eg, ScalaCheck, QuickCheck) a single test could replace several unit tests as special cases. Then the whole testing hierarchy is flattened. Property testing fits maths/numerical applications particularly well, but at a computational cost.

A complementary approach, in line with the OP's hunches, is to use a testing framework amenable to a hierarchy of tests. This goes towards  behaviour-driven development (BDD). You could have a high-level function (= BDD "Feature") and low-level supporting functions ( = BDD "Scenarios"). BDD testing tools easily accommodate this hierarchy. Some of them have nice GUIs visually organising, if not diagramming, it. In addition, they can serve as living documentation.

*Some BDD references/search terms: "BDD In Action", Dan North, cucumber, serenity tool.*